# How to delete a record, a special value in Unix with the comma separated file n

Tags: linux, text-processing, csv

How to delete a record, a special value in Unix with the comma separated file n

My data

```
100,india,*,*,P,45000,location
200,india,*,*,*,45000,location
300,india,*,*,P,45000,location
400,india,*,*,*,45000,location
```

wherever P is there in 5th position I want delete those records.
required output

```
200,india,*,*,*,45000,location
400,india,*,*,*,45000,location
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
awk -F, '{if ($5 != "P") { print $0 }}' /path/to/input-file
```

Comment: or more idiomatically `awk -F, '$5 != "P"' path/to/input-file`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I want to delete those records in original input file

Comment: @user377329 `GNU Awk` since version 4.1.0 has the option [in-place](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html)

Answer (score 0):

You use the /linux tag, so you surely have GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -E '/^([^,]*,){4}P/d' data.txt
```

- `-i` to edit the file in place
- `-E` to use extended regular expressions for better readability
- `[^,]*` matches a sequence without comma, so
- `^([^,]*,){4}` matches the four first fields
- if those are followed by a `P`, `d`elete that line